# Filter through array to return only one value if more than one exists

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to filter through an array to return only one city name if more than one of its kind exists.

For example, the ideal output for the bottom code would be:

new york

ohio

mars

---- this is the current output ----

new york

ohio

new york

mars

```
var people = [{
    name: "jack",
    age: 22,
    city: "new york"
}, {
    name: "john",
    age: 35,
    city: "ohio"
}, {
    name: "travis",
    age: 21,
    city: "new york"
}, {
    name: "david",
    age: 42,
    city: "mars"
}];

for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    console.log(people[i].city);   
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q3nj6ey1/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to a new array if the city doesn't already exist in it.

```
var cities  = [];
var numPeople = people.length;
for (var i = 0; i < numPeople; i++) {
    if(cities.indexOf(people[i].city) == -1){
        cities.push(people[i].city);
    }
}
```

Then you can print your array if you wish:

```
for(var i=0;i<cities.length;i++){
    console.log(cities[i]);
}
```